# Wordpress clicking on link kills session

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, session

I have website using wordpress and is also using the Zend framework.

When i click on a link in wordress, when directing to the zend framework it removes my session.

What could be the reasons for this?

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation [here](http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session) of how WordPress unsets session variables, and a possible solution. Unfortunately it seems to require modifying core files - there don't seem to be any hooks in `wp_unregister_GLOBALS` that would help.

There's more discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441240/wordpress-session-management).