# Wordpress $_SESSION not working even after adding add_action('init, '...',1)

Tags: wordpress, session

I'm trying to make SESSION works with Wordpress but it can't work even I added the below code to my plugin but nothing happen:

```
add_action('init', 'simpleSessionStart', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'simpleSessionDestroy');
add_action('wp_login', 'simpleSessionDestroy');

function simpleSessionStart() {
    if(!session_id())session_start();
}

function simpleSessionDestroy() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

How can I make $_SESSION passing date from one page to another in my wordpress site

My wordpress version is: 3.5.2

My theme is: twentyeleven

Answer (score 18):

Place this code in your functions.php file

```
function sess_start() {
    if (!session_id())
    session_start();
}
add_action('init','sess_start');
```

Comment: I was calling session_start() on pages and it had been working fine, updated to latest WP and it broke, adding this function fixed it! thanks!

Comment: Ruddy hell.. Can confirm this was causing our session vars not to persist too. Adding this fixed it for us also.

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441240/wordpress-session-management/2514042#2514042) for a discussion of using `$_SESSION` with WordPress.  In short, WordPress removes session variables if `register_globals` is defined.

The comments on the question itself point to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-use-my-own-custom-session-value-in-wordpress/72744#72744) on the WordPress stackexchange, which discusses a plugin that may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Hobo, I'm trying to do one of these methods