# Wordpress PHP include external php file with sessions not saving sessions

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am using a *wordpress* plugin called *PHP Code* where i use php include (`<?php include 'file.php'; ?>` to include external php files.

The files i am including are for a seperate login form using php sessions.

When i login as a user on the external/included page inside my wordpress site its not saving the sessions.. if i `echo $_SESSION["variable"];` on the login submit page it shows the value but isn't saving it when the page changes

Comment: If you need to alter the login form, why not using the WordPress API for achieving that? http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form

Comment: the other login its a completely separate database etc linking to an internal ticketing system. the php files are already setup ready to be included so i want to just use those

Comment: Not certain, but it may be because WordPress removes session variables if register_globals is defined - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441240/wordpress-session-management)