# store form value into session after submit and save until form submit again: PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to save form value into PHP session and want to keep save all form value until form submit:

I have trying like this:

```
$pattern = '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) :
   $s1 =  $_REQUEST['step1'];
   $s2 = $_REQUEST['step2'];
   $s3 = $_REQUEST['step3'];
   $s4 = $_REQUEST['step4'];
$pattern .= $s1.$s2.$s3;
$p_cat= $_REQUEST['p_cat'];

$_SESSION['mywine'] =  $pattern;
$_SESSION['quantity'] =  $_REQUEST['step4'];

if($p_cat == 'mixed')
$p_cat = 'red,white';
else $p_cat=  $_REQUEST['p_cat'];
endif;



 $my_wine = $_SESSION['mywine'];
 $qun = $_SESSION['quantity'];

         $args = array(
             'post_type' => 'product',
                 'product_cat' => $p_cat,
                   'posts_per_page' => 3,
                           'meta_query' => array(
                              array(
                               'key' => 'product_score_pattern',
                                'value' => $my_wine,
                                'compare' => '='
                                )
                               )
                             );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

                 endwhile;
                endif;
```

This code able to save data into session but when I will refresh page then session value will be empty.

I want to keep form vale until form submit. How this will be possible?

Comment: `session_start();` is there ?

Comment: yes I have used session_start();

Comment: can you post your full code??

Comment: Have you enabled cookies in your browser ?

Comment: I have added my full code and I want session to save my result @Saty

Comment: yes @JitendraPurohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `session_start()` before to assign or access `$_SESSION` variable like below.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) :
 $_SESSION['sessionvalue'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
endif;
echo $_SESSION['sessionvalue'];
```

Okay, you are using wordpress, it is not allowing create session.. you need to refer this

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sessions-not-working-tried-everything

[Wordpress session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441240/wordpress-session-management/2514042#2514042)

Comment: I have already added session_start()  and it will save value into session but I want to keep save this value until next submit