# Update DB after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to carry a variable over to disable.php which will then update a row in the database, all of this is within a wordpress plugin I am building. I cannot see why this won't work.

Heres my form

```html
<form method='post' action='".plugins_url()."/myremovalsquote/inc/disable.php''>
  <input type='submit' name='".$_SESSION['id'] = $active_partner->partner_id."' class='button-primary' id='disable' value='Disable'/>
</form>
```

Heres my /disable.php

```
global $wpdb;

$id = $_SESSION["id"];

$wpdb->query("UPDATE partners SET active='no' WHERE partner_id='".$id."'");

header("Location: http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin-settings");
```

This is the error I am getting, it seems that the variable from the session isn't being carried over to disable.php.

Comment: Why not use a hidden input (`<input type="hidden" name="some_weird_sessionid" value=12345>`) ?

Comment: You edit adds "This is the error I am getting..." but I do not see the error. Did you forget to add it? Also, from what I can tell, this probably isn't working because wordpress doesn't use sessions by default. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441240/wordpress-session-management) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-use-my-own-custom-session-value-in-wordpress) for my sources for that theory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment, you could either use a hidden input field or store the values to be read and sent in the session alltogether. For the first solution:

```
<form method='post' action='/myremovalsquote/inc/disable.php'>
<input type="hidden" name="id_to_be_disabled" value="<?= $active_partner->partner_id; ?>">
  <input type='submit' class='button-primary' id='disable' value='Disable'/>
</form>
```

For the second solution just invoke the session with `session_start();` and store the value in it. No need to fiddle around with the submit button name.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your form with name and value. Try this:

```
<form method='post' action='".plugins_url()."/myremovalsquote/inc/disable.php"'>
  <input type='submit' name='id' value='" . $active_partner->partner_id."' class='button-primary' id='disable' value='Disable'/>
</form>
```

And I also would prefer a hidden field here.

Answer (score -1):

put session_start() on your /disable.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your code: why does it works? What should it do?